# Get the content of whole div and paste that to another with different class

Tags: javascript

Here's my js:

```
  const cc = e.target.parentElement.children[1].children[1].outerHTML;
  console.log(cc);
  imgText.outerHTML = cc;
```

It copies the whole div with the class that has `display:none` and it relocated that to another place, but it keeps the class and doesn't show.

The example what the `const cc` gets:

```
<div class="img-text row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <p class="img-text">
                test2
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <p class="img-text">
                test
            </p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Class `img-text` has css of `display:none`. Any way I can change the class or change the css of the class?

Another question, Is there a way to get the whole giv content another way than:

```
e.target.parentElement.children[1].children[1].outerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change the display class to block in the new div by adding this

```
.style.display = "block";
```

Before putting the content into the new div